# In Apple Logic 9, what are "GM Device" tracks?

Tags: midi

I'm trying to open a MIDI file in Logic Pro 9, and the tracks are being placed on "GM Device" tracks, which don't have any inserts, meaning I cannot add instruments or effects to them.

What are these GM Device tracks, and is the only way to fix it to create new Software Instrument tracks and move the regions across manually? This is quite a tedious process in large MIDI files.

Comment: I don't know Pro Logic, but I'm guessing that your MIDI files contain [General MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Parameter_interpretations) instrument type information and that Pro Logic acts upon that. Guess this doesn't help you though...

Comment: They do, yes. But I'd rather they opened on Software Instrument tracks so that I can add instruments to them, if possible.

Comment: I don't know logic pro either, but this might help : http://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=48799

Answer (score 2):

These are tracks that are not configured for use with virtual instruments running on your computer. Rather, they are configured to be used with an external hardware synthesizer or sample player or keyboard, connected using MIDI cables. The MIDI note data that is output from Logic is given patch number or instrument assignments according to the General MIDI Specification.

The reason that they don't have any inserts or effects set up for them is that these tracks don't work with audio: they just send MIDI signals from Logic to the MIDI Out ports on your MIDI interface to an external keyboard or rack-mount hardware device. You would typically take the audio outputs from such a device, run them into the audio inputs of your multi-channel external hardware audio interface, and record the audio from them onto other tracks, and on those other tracks you could add inserts or effects within Logic.

Answer (score 1):

Logic uses these tracks to send information to an external device. If you want to record an external device then you would probally record this onto another track.

For example:
I recently recorded an Oberheim, the information on the "device track" sents the info to th oberheim, next, the oberheim sends the info to a Logic audio track.

How to solve your problem: just create a softsynh track and copy your midi info into this track.
Don't get confused in the use of midi though, midi is just "info for playing a device" this "device" can be hosted in your computer or externally.